# Replace text tags inside txt file python3

Tags: python-3.x, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to make a proxy **scraper** , this is my code:

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import lxml
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

meh=[]

pathf = '/home/user/tests.txt'

url = Request('https://www.path.to/table', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

page_html = urlopen(url).read()

page_soup = soup(page_html, features="xml")

final = page_soup.tbody

meh.append(final)

with open(pathf, 'w') as f:
    with redirect_stdout(f):
        print(meh[0].text.strip())
```

Now i want the text to show in a more readable way, because its like this:

> 12.183.20.3615893USUnited StatesSocks5AnonymousYes11 seconds ago220.133.97.7445657TWTaiwanSocks5AnonymousYes11 seconds ago

How can i turn this text into a more readable file? something like:

> 12.183.20.36 15893 US United States Socks5 Anonymous Yes 11 seconds ago (new line) ...

Here is the actual output without the '.text.strip()' format after a jsbeautifier trip if it helps
https://ghostbin.com/paste/g56qe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract all `td` elements as list instead of extracting complete table body:

```
final_list = page_soup.findAll('td')
```

and then get list of text nodes:

```
list_of_text_nodes = [td.text.strip() for td in final_list]
```

*Output*:

```
[u'182.235.38.81', u'40748', u'TW', u'Taiwan', u'Socks5', u'Anonymous'...]
```

or get all text nodes as single string:

```
complete_text = " ".join([i.text.strip() for i in final_list])
```

*Output*:

```
'182.235.38.81 40748 TW Taiwan Socks5 Anonymous Yes 14 seconds ago ...'
```